# User input handler that returns data to page

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress developing and I have found what feels like a clumsy solution to a problem that seems like it should be common. Please help me find a cleaner solution with less potential for buggy behavior.

**Objective:** Get date range from user on a Wordpress page, use date range in API request, display data from API response on Wordpress page.

**Current solution:** Start and end dates are submitted via an HTML form in a Wordpress page with POST method. The POST request does not route to any other page. In addition to `start` and `end` parameters, the form has a hidden `action` parameter with a custom value I have specified: `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom-value">`. I have written a plugin that uses the `init` hook. The hooked function checks `$_REQUEST['action']` to see if it matches the custom value in the form, and if so it does a GET request to an API (recreation.gov) using the `start` and `end` dates from the form. Up to this point, the solution seems pretty solid to me. Here's where the tutorials ran out and I had to get......inventive.
The data from the API request is processed and formatted into HTML, and this string is stored as a transient using `set_transient` with a 3 second lifespan. In the original page that the form was submitted from, there is a shortcode that simply returns the transient. Now I have the data from the API on the same page that the user specified the date range from.

This solution works, but seems like there is a high probability of things going awry if multiple users are using the page at the same time, and seeing or overwriting each others' results. There must be a better way to get the data from the plugin that does the API request back to the Wordpress page.

Since this question is about methodology, not syntax, I haven't included any example code, but I could if that would be helpful. Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up finding was ditching the plugin and doing everything from inside a shortcode. Shortcode has access to `$_REQUEST['action']`, which I wasn't aware of, so I was able to get the user input and do the API call in the shortcode, then format the results and return them. No need to deal with plugins and hooks because the shortcode is executed as the page is loaded.